# How do i set my lockscreen wallpaper?

Tags: 8.0, lumia

I set a wallpaper as lockscreen but again a blank screen appears as my lock seeen. How do i set my lockscreen wallpaper?

Comment: It seems like you had two questions here, so I just left the first. Can you please also add some details e.g. what type and size image you used.

Comment: Is there any lock screen changing application installed and configured (like facebook or something)? If yes it'll try to update your lock screen periodically.

Answer (score 4):

You may have "High Contrast" toggled on. If so, the lock screen/wallpaper will be black even after you set a picture or whatever.

If this is the case, go to settings-> ease of access and slide the "High Contrast" switch off.

Comment: Good catch, didn't know high contrast would replace the picture you set.